# how to deal with multiple clients in c++ socket problem?

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp

I need some help with a socket program with multiple clients and one server. To simplify, I create

- 3 socket `clients`
- 1 socket server
- For each client, it opens a new connection for sending a new message and closes the connection after a response is received.
- For the server, it does not need to deal with connections concurrently, it can deal with the message one by one

here is my code (runnable), compile it with `/usr/bin/g++ mycode.cpp -g -lpthread -lrt -Wall -o mycode`

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

void Warning(string msg) { std::cout<< msg << std::endl; }
     
namespace mySocket {
    class Memcached {
    public:
        // start a server
        static void controller(int port=7111) { std::thread (server, port).detach(); }

        // open a new connection to send a message: 
        //  1. open a connection
        //  2. send the message
        //  3. read the message
        //  4. close the connection
        std::string sendMessage(string msg, string host, int port=7111) {
            int sock = 0, client_fd;
            struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
            char buffer[1024] = { 0 };
            if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) {
                std::cout << "Socket creation error, msg: " << msg << ", host: " << host << ", port: " << port << std::endl;
                exit(1);
            }
            serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
            serv_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
            if (inet_pton(AF_INET, host.c_str(), &serv_addr.sin_addr) <= 0) {
                std::cout << "\nInvalid address/ Address not supported, kmsgey: " << msg << ", host: " << host << ", port: " << port << std::endl;
                exit(1);
            }
            while ((client_fd = connect(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr))) < 0) { sleep(10*1000); }
            std::cout << "client sends a message:"<<msg<<", msg size:"<<msg.size()<<std::endl;
            send(sock, msg.c_str(), msg.size(), 0);
            read(sock, buffer, 1024);
            close(client_fd);
            return std::string(buffer, strlen(buffer));
        }

     private:
        // start a server
        //  1. open a file descriptor
        //  2. listen the fd with queue size 10
        //  3. accept one connection at a time
        //  4. deal with message in the connection
        //  5. accept the next connection
        //  6. repeat step 3
        static void server(int port) {
            int server_fd, new_socket;
            struct sockaddr_in address;
            int opt = 1;
            int addrlen = sizeof(address);
            char buffer[1024] = { 0 };
            unordered_map<string,string> data;
            if ((server_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == 0) {
                Warning("socket failed"); exit(1);
            }
            if (setsockopt(server_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR | SO_REUSEPORT, &opt, sizeof(opt))) {
                Warning("setsockopt failed"); exit(1);
            }
            address.sin_family = AF_INET;
            address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
            address.sin_port = htons(port);
            if (bind(server_fd, (struct sockaddr*)&address, sizeof(address)) < 0) {
                Warning("bind failed"); exit(1);
            }
            // the queue size is 10 > 3
            if (listen(server_fd, 10) < 0) {
                Warning("listen failed"); exit(1);
            }
            while(1)
            {
                if ((new_socket = accept(server_fd, (struct sockaddr*)&address, (socklen_t*)&addrlen)) < 0) {
                    std::cout << "accept failed"; exit(1);
                }
                memset(&buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer)); //clear the buffer
                read(new_socket, buffer, 1024);
                std::string msg = std::string(buffer, strlen(buffer));
                if (msg.size()==0) {
                    std::cout<<"I can't believe it"<<std::endl;
                }
                std::cout<<"received msg from the client:"<<msg<<",msg size:"<<msg.size()<<std::endl;
                std::string results="response from the server:["+msg+"]";
                send(new_socket, results.c_str(), results.length(), 0);
                //usleep(10*1000);
            }
            if (close(new_socket)<0){
                std::cout <<"close error"<<std::endl; 
            }
            shutdown(server_fd, SHUT_RDWR);
        }
    } ;
}

void operation(int client_id) {
    auto obj = new mySocket::Memcached();
    for (int i=0; i<10;i++){
        int id=client_id*100+i;
        std::cout<<obj->sendMessage(std::to_string(id), "127.0.0.1", 7111)<<std::endl<<std::endl;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char const* argv[]) {
    // start a socket server
    mySocket::Memcached::controller();
    
    // start 3 socket clients
    std::thread t1(operation, 1);
    std::thread t2(operation, 2);
    std::thread t3(operation, 3);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();
}
```

In the code above, the client always sends a message with a length of 3. However, the server can receive messages **with a length of 0 which causes further errors**.

I'm struggling with this for several days and can't figure out why it happens. I noticed

- if I add a short `sleep` inside the server `while loop`, the problem is solved. (uncomment `usleep(10*1000);` in the code).
- or if I only use one client, the problem is also solved.

Any thought helps.

Comment: I recommend stepping back a bit and getting some of the fundamentals down before ramping up the difficulty. For example, when a socket read returns with a length of zero, that means the socket has been disconnected. This is something you have to expect and handle.

Comment: That you're not utilizing the return result of `read` is just asking for trouble. It's there for a reason, and you should be using it.  You're also leaking a socket descriptor with every client connection. The `close` call should be in the same scope as the successful `accept`.

Comment: Sidenote: Read the tag information. `asio` is for an audio protocol.

Comment: 1. **read returns 0**. That's true, I noticed that the server receives the 0-length message, but I've not figured it out yet;  2. **leaking a socket descriptor**. It's also true,  and it can't help for the issue;  3. `asio` is an option, but I don't want to use `boost`;  4. **message-oriented**. Yes, that's the reason I let the client send the fixed length of the message with 3, and receive it with 1024 `read(new_socket, buffer, 1024);`

Comment: you are also making the fundamental assumption that tcp traffic is message oriented; it is not. A send message of 50 bytes can be receives as 25 2 byte receives, you must loop on the read/recv until you have read the whole message. That in turn means you must know how big the message is, so prepend a length or add a terminal sequence

Answer (score 1):

You are using TCP sockets. You may want to use some application-level protocol like HTTP, websockets instead, that will be much easier, because you will not need to worry about how message is sent/received and in which sequence. If you have to stick with TCP sockets, you firstly have to understand few things:

- There's two types of TCP sockets you can use: **non-blocking** and **blocking IO** (input/output). You are currently using blocking IO. That IO will be sometimes blocked and you won't be able to do anything with sockets. In blocking IO, it can be work arounded by using **one socket per thread** on server-side. It's not efficient, but it's relatively easy comparing to Non-blocking IO. Non-blocking IO doesn't wait for anything. While in blocking IO you wait for data, in non-blocking IO you create something like events, callbacks, that are used when there's some data. You probably have to read about these types of IO.
- In your `server` function, would be better, if you listen for incoming connections in one thread, and when there's incoming connection, move this connection into another thread and function, that will handle other things. This may solve your problem related to multiple clients at the same time.
- In function `operation`, instead of allocating memory using raw pointer, use static allocation or smart pointers to avoid memory leaks. If you don't want to, then at least, do `delete obj;` in the end of function.
- And the last one thing. You can use some TCP socket wrapper like `sockpp` to make things a lot easier. You will have anything TCP sockets have, but in C++ style and a little bit easier to understand and maintain. If you can't use application-level protocol, I strongly suggest you to use some wrapper at least.

### Update

As was stated by commenters, there are more things you need to know:

- TCP sockets are streams. This means that if you send your message with length of 1024 bytes, it can be divided into several TCP data packets and you can't know if it will be divided or not, how much packets other side will receive etc. You have to read in a while loop using `recv()` and wait for data. There's some tricks which can help you to properly receive data:

  - You can send length of your message  first, so other side will know how much bytes it needs to receive.
  - You can place some terminating symbol or sequence of terminating symbols in the end of your message and read until these will be received. This can be a little risky, because there's chance that you would not receive these symbols at all and will be reading next.
- You have to `join` client threads only when you know, that server is already started and listening for incoming connections. You can use some variable as a flag for these purposes, but make note, that you have to pay a lot of attention, when reading/writing variable from two or more different threads. For these purposes, you can use mutexes, which are some mechanism that will allow you safely access one variable from several threads.

Comment: You also cannot be guaranteed that the server thread started in `controller` will start before the client threads start, find there is no listener on the port they need to talk to, and give up.

Comment: Thank you for the long comment. For some reason, I have to use raw socket programming. For suggestions: (1) (2) you're right, but for simplicity and ease to solve the problem, I let the server only deal with one connection at one time to avoid multi-threads (3) (4) yes, I need to do those optimizations and refactors after fixing the issue.

Comment: On re-read, the clients don't give up, but the code seems be very brittle and prone to locking up.

Comment: Another trick is to make strings like this: `std::string msg = std::string(buffer, len);` where `len` is the value returned by `read`, after checking to make sure it is greater than zero (and handling any errors reported)

Comment: I will try to use `recv` instead of read. But do I really need to use mutex? (1) on the client side, I use different `obj` and all variables are local variables, so there is no data race; (2) on the server side, I always let the server deal with one connection at a time, so there is also no data race.

Comment: @stickers you launch clients and server in the main thread, but there can be situation when server is not launched yet and main thread launches clients. In the server thread, you have to somehow give information to main thread, that server is launched and clients now can be launched safely. One of the ways how this can be done is global `bool` variable that will be set to true in server thread, and in the main thread you are waiting while this var won't be true.  While this is not the best solution, it's suggestion to remember about data races when using multiple threads and global variables.

Comment: @stickers Threads make things a lot more complicated and unless they are used carefully probably slow a program down rather than speed it up. Here you can use POSIX's [`select` function](https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/#select) and do the whole thing in a single thread. For bigger jobs, use smarter tools like [libevent](https://libevent.org/) or Windows's [Overlapped IO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/synchronization-and-overlapped-input-and-output)

Comment: Rather than sharing a raw `bool` across multiple threads consider using an `atomic<bool>` or an `atomic_flag`. The `bool` is probably an atomic operation (can't be interrupted), but compilers are within their rights to do stuff like optimize `boolean_flag = true; while (boolean_flag)` into `while (true)` and save on the test if they can't see `boolean_flag` being changed inside the loop.   It won't even look at the possibility of the value being updated in another thread unless you make it check.